# Does Sphinx support a no wrap option for building the po files?

Tags: python-sphinx

I am trying to create po files in sphinx using
sphinx-intl update -p build/locale/ -l de.

However, the output it produces looks something like

```
#: ../../source/my-documentation.rst:16
msgid ""
"Far quitting dwelling graceful the likewise received building. "
"Unaffected remarkably get yet introduced excellence terminated led."
"But truth being state can she china widow."
msgstr ""
```

While what I want is:

```
#: ../../source/my-documentation.rst:16
msgid ""
"Far quitting dwelling graceful the likewise received building. Unaffected remarkably get yet introduced excellence terminated led. But truth being state can she china widow."
msgstr ""
```

Is there any way I can specify a no-wrap option?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source code of `sphinx-intl`, it is not possible to configure.

You can see it [here](https://bitbucket.org/shimizukawa/sphinx-intl/src/5bbb60b8ebac312f34624b56d4bd764fa647fae7/sphinx_intl/commands.py?at=default#cl-267). `sphinx-intl` calls `pofile` function without `wrapwidth` argument. However, polib library supports what you need, so you can either fork `sphinx-intl`, or monkey patch it, and call `pofile` function with e.g. `wrapwidth=150`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is a parameter to set the length of the lines in the `po` files: `--line-width`.

For example:

```
sphinx-intl update -p build/gettext -l es -l ja --line-width=120
```

You can set this parameter to be a very long number.

This was implemented to Sphinx in 2019 with the enhancement [#28](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx-intl/issues/28).